# Send Sms using SMPP in .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core

Is there is a way connect SMPP server and send SMS using SMPP protocal if I am using .NET Core? I need a bare simple way to send SMS using SMPP in .NET Core?

Comment: Have you found a reliable solution?

Comment: Unfortunately we used Diafaan tool to manage our SMS